# TestDisk Error with no solution

Tags: apt, dependencies

I got errors when installing "testdisk". How can I troubleshoot this issue?

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 testdisk : 
 Depends: libntfs-3g861 but it is not installable
 Depends: ntfs-3g but it is not installable
```

)

```
testdisk:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 7.0-1
Version table:
 7.0-1 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
ntfs-3g:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? (or check your pasted package name).  I get errors for the first https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libntfs-3g861 , and answers (ie. availability) for the second https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ntfs-3g . Your issue is the `libntfs-3g861` so either your `testdisk` is coming from a non-Ubuntu source, or you've copied the package name incorrectly.  Your report errors for both, so I"d check your sources.list* file(s)  for `ntfs-3g`

Comment: So... how can i fix for that?

Comment: As for your first, I see https://packages.ubuntu.com/libntfs-3g872 in the repos  - so what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Version is Ubuntu 16.04.4

Comment: can you please add (to your question) the result of `apt-cache policy testdisk ntfs-3g`  (i'm leaving out the one I didn't find)

Comment: updated above..

Comment: I would check your /etc/apt/sources.list by entering `cat /etc/apt/sources.list |grep ^deb.*xenial` *(lines that start with 'deb' [0 or more chars] then 'xenial')* checking 'main' is there (`testdisk` comes from universe, `libntfs-3g` comes from main with updated versions in xenial-updates & xenial-security. *info from my own 16.04.4 `apt-cache policy`*

Comment: deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe multiverse

Comment: please add a " main" to that line (after xenial, your line allows packages from universe & multiverse but *not* from 'main'.  it should say ".. xenial main universe multi.."  *(I have 'restricted' too for my personal machines)*  You can then `sudo apt update` & try again..